# How should I report logistic regression on a poster?

Tags: regression, logistic, data-visualization, reporting

An example of my odds ratio bar chart:
[image]

I am developing a poster that reports on a research project I've been working on this summer. For the project, I ran a logistic regression with 1 continuous predictor and 7 binary predictors in r. Three of those predictors were significant and to show this on the poster, I reported the odds ratios of those predictors using a simple bar chart.

Given that this is a simple poster meant for a general audience, I did not include the 95% CI on the forest plot graph so as not to overwhelm with data. Instead I want to include all information about the model in a small footnote.

My question is, what information do I need to include about the model in the footnote? Should I calculate a pseudo-R2 for the full model and report that along with the degrees of freedom? Do I need to specify the p values and 95% CIs for each significant predictor individually? I only have a small space with which to do this so I want to be selective about which information is included.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have questions about sharing results from statistical models, you should ask for statistical advice at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: OK will do thanks!

Comment: I think we need a bit more context here. It looks like your poster may be related to a medical subject. What do you mean by a general audience? Do you mean a general healthcare audience, an audience of physicians, pharmacists, nurses, etc? I think in most cases you should use a forest plot with confidence intervals. Use a log scale for the odds ratio, and don't use bars (which to my mind don't make a lot of sense with odds ratios). If you think your audience won't understand confidence intervals, then it's not clear why you think you will need DOF and pseudo-R^2.

Comment: In response to @Allan's post, my audience is meant to be non-medical professionals but if medical professionals read it, the poster should have the information they need. I've seen this type of bar plot utilized in order to appeal to a non-scientific audience and I think it visualizes the point well. But I am not sure whether it has all the information necessary for a more advanced audience.